# CSS Isolation in Azure Not Rendering Properly

Tags: blazor-server-side, azure-webapps, asp.net-core-css-isolation

I have setup the Blazor Server template and published it to my sandbox site:

https://scg-apps-demo-ddl.azurewebsites.net/

When it loads, the CSS isolation engages and sets up the tags appropriately. For example:

```
<div class="top-row px-4" b-wjui9y5cp2=""><a href="https://docs.microsoft.com/aspnet/" target="_blank" b-wjui9y5cp2="">About</a></div>
```

The CSS does not render at all. When I load the actual CSS for it, the IDs are fixed and will not regenerate and synchronize with the HTML markup: https://scg-apps-demo-ddl.azurewebsites.net/SCG.Apps.Ext.DemoDDL.styles.css

I tried enabling UseStaticWebAssets and it did not work:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.WebHost.UseStaticWebAssets();
```

I also disabled CSS isolation and that did not work either.

Any ideas?

Comment: I've seen some related CSS isolation issues where the isolation identifiers get out of sync with each other: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65547764/blazor-webassembly-css-isolation-scoped-identities-doesnt-match

I keep seeing the workaround to clean the project, or delete the contents in the bin/obj folders to force the css to be regenerated.

Are you able to have Azure clean or delete the bin/obj folders on deploy?